# DateTime is not correct when querying from sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

Im using `AzureMobileServices` for sync data but using `SQLite` for retrieving data because I could not get anything working for executing raw queries in azure services.

Im able to get records but my problem is with DateTime column in table.
I always get weird date like 01/01/0001 or something like this.

Things I have tried:

```
Parse<Model>().Query("select datetime(CreatedAt, 'unixepoch') CreatedAt from table"); 

Parse<Model>().Query("select strftime('%d/%m/%Y',CreatedAt / 10000000 - 62135596800,'unixepoch')   as createdAt from table");
```

Only time I get correct date and time when I run execute scalar and parse it into string like this:

```
connection.ExecuteScalar<string>("select datetime(CreatedAt, 'unixepoch') as createdAt from table limit 1");
```

Its not being parsed into my Model properly which has this property

`public DateTime? CreatedAt {get; set;}`

Edit

This is how it looks in sqlite

[image: Schema of Datetime column]
Any suggestion?

Comment: You maybe have to parse to DateTime and convert to string with propery format for your model. How is the date stored? In which format?

Comment: I haven't worked with AzureMobileServices before, and after some searching it may be because of your null `?` property. Try changing it to `Nullable<DateTime>` instead. See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16692647/why-when-i-insert-a-datetime-null-i-have-0001-01-01-in-sql-server/16692795#16692795

Comment: the thing i do not understand is that this is working:
`ExecuteScalar<string>("select strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',datetime(CreatedAt,'unixepoch')) from tblRegister limit 1")`

whereas ExecuteScalar<Datetime>(same query) does not work

Comment: @RobScott i tried Nullable<DateTime> but the issue remains same.

Comment: @AwaisShaikh well in that case, your `Parse<Model>().Query(....` has `%d/%m/%Y`, instead of `%m/%d/%Y`, as you commented above

Comment: @AwaisShaikh see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41516093/cannot-read-nullable-datetime-value-from-sqlite-db-using-net-core-and-entity-fr perhaps?

Comment: @RobScott i tried all formats but nothing gave me correct datetime. All primitive datatypes return correct data in `ExecuteScalar` method, string gives me `10/02/2019 15:55:00` , double gives me `10`..

Comment: The value returned is definitely relating to a `DBNull.Value` and the property the model is assigning too. Please post your table's column's datatypes and your whole model

Comment: @RobScott I have edited my question with schema of the column

Answer (score 0):

DateTime default value is 01/01/0001.Check the methods you use to create the model. The CreatedAt property throws a default value because of an incompatibility.